# Wrapping text in facet_grid from one of multiple factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

If I have multiple factors in a facet_grid (something like `facet_grid(cyl ~ am + vs)`, is it possible to wrap text from just one of them (just `am` and not `vs`)? Let's use the MTCARS df as an example, but instead of 0s and 1s for `am`, imagine I have very long labels. :

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2$am <- factor(mtcars2$am,
                    levels = c(0,1),
                    labels = c("this is a very very very looooooooooooong label", 
                               "this is also a very very very looooooooooooong label"))

ggplot(mtcars2, aes(wt,mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cyl ~ am + vs)
```

this produces this plot: [image: Long_Labels]

I can wrap that variable using `labeller = label_wrap_gen()`, which increases the height of that box rather substantially (mostly fine with that), but the height of the box containing `vs` is the same height as the new height for `am`. Because my second factor is small (0/1), it doesn't need to be the same height as that of the first factor.

[image: Long_labels wrapped]

In my actual dataset, my plot is a 7 x 6 grid, and my labels wrap to like 6 lines (they aren't all that long, really, it's just that there are so many boxes, the width of each individual plot is much narrower, so, I need all space I can get to make this look ok.

Comment: Can you add example output for the long label version? It's hard to picture exactly what you're describing. Also, try to limit a post to one question—maybe split the second question out into another standalone post

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have edited the post.

Comment: General suggestion: If you have a lot of facets crammed in and long labels, maybe it would be good to take a step back and figure out if you 1) really need all those facets at once, and 2) really need all the text in the labels. When I run into similar space problems, I reevaluate whether I actually need all of what I'm trying to plot; a lot of the time, I don't

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about specifically wrapping one of the labels, but the ggh4x package has some additional options for strips that sound appropriate for some other parts of your question.

Let's first edit the example to actually show the problem you're encountering. In the plot below, you can see that the Yes/No labels are given  too much space relative to their size.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- mtcars
df <- transform(
  df,
  am = ifelse(am, "I'm a label that is too long", 
              "I'm an even longer label that exceeds strip boundaries"),
  vs = ifelse(vs, "Yes", "No")
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point()
p + facet_grid(cyl ~ am + vs, labeller = label_wrap_gen())
```

[image]

The facets in ggh4x accept a `strip` argument (more info [here](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#strips-1)) that you can use to trim the excess space, but also to set one of the layers to use bold text instead of plain text.

```r
library(ggh4x)
#> Warning: package 'ggh4x' was built under R version 4.1.1
p + facet_grid2(
  cyl ~ am + vs, labeller = label_wrap_gen(),
  strip = strip_themed(
    size = "variable", # Shrinks 2nd layer
    text_x = elem_list_text(face = c(1, 2)), # 2nd layer in bold
    by_layer_x = TRUE
  ))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x